# an OS X application that uses two display monitors / changes its display monitor in runtime

Tags: objective-c, macos, uiscreen

I want to create a photo viewer that uses two displays: one normal display (1920x1080) and the other one is rotated (1080x1920). I'm doing this to maximize the photo size - landscape pictures would be displayed on the normal display in, and portrait photos on the rotated one. both in full screen.

There's actually no need for the application to be displayed simultaneously on the two displays, just switch between displays according to current image ratio, during a slideshow.

So How do I tell the app to be displayed on a specific screen?

Comment: So, I found a different solution eventually:

Comment: I am running two apps, one for each  display, and the main one tells the second one what to display, using NSConnection.  a bit of  a hassle but it works!